# MySQL ExceptionInInitializerError Java JDBC on Startup

Tags: java, database, security, jdbc, applet

I am making a simple applet that uses an SQL Database. 
When I use this applet locally on Netbeans it runs fine without a problem, yet when I deploy it to the Web I am getting a weird error. 
I am using Java 1.6 locally, and the server I deploy on is running Java 1.6

 I am using J2BC 5.1.22.
This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:315)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at FinalProject.DBConnect.<init>(DBConnect.java:29)
at FinalProject.TriviaApplet.init(TriviaApplet.java:61)
at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
    ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.encoding" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:70)
```

The code I use to initialize the driver is:

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "db", "pw");
```

Does any one have any insight as to why this is occuring?

To add, my Applet gets all the information from another class. ^ The above is from DBConnect Class. An instance of this class is created, and this class does all the DB work.
It was a requirement for this to be done as an applet.
I have signed both my jar, and the lib jar containing the JDBC driver.

Comment: "access denied" - permissions...

Comment: I do have my Applet Jar file's signed though. (Did not sign the lib file)

Comment: Why are you executing JDBC in an applet in first place? What exactly made you to choose for this very unsafe approach? You're exposing the DB login and scheme into the public this way. You should rather execute the JDBC only in the server side, mediated by some servlet or webservice.

Comment: 1) The applet should not be able to access the DB directly, but instead through an interface that mediates what it does. 2) If the applet is 'phoning home' to either the DB or the interface, the applet can be sand-boxed, but it requires forming the `connectionURL` from (relative to) the document base or code base of the applet.  Barring that, it would be necessary to digitally sign the applet, to access the foreign server. 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"Did not sign the lib file"*  In a trusted applet ***all*** jars need to be digitally signed (unless deployed using JWS and the unsigned Jars are in a separate extension).

Comment: I am not executing JDBC in an applet per say, I created a class, DBConnect; where all the database work is done. DBConnect is where the db connection is, and it passes the data to the applet.

Comment: I did sign the lib file, and same error.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don't think a SSSCE would help, since this does work locally and is only a problem when I deploy to a server.

Comment: *"this does work locally"*  That is not relevant since Netbeans does not impose a sand-box (AFAIR).

Comment: In your comment above, can you clarify how I would sand-box my applet so my other class can reach the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is due to the web security problem. how your JDBC driver is deployed to the client? do you give them enought permission? in fact, using JDBC in applet to visit the database in value-less.

1. it requires all the client must have JRE installed and JDBC driver in CLASSPATH, you can try to package the JDBC driver with your applet in a same JAR.
2. it need the policy modification by grant the socket connection in every local JRE.

`permission java.net.SocketPermission "10.6.1.16:1521", "connect, resolve";`

that make this solution nearly useless..

Comment: I only moved the JDBC jar file to the lib folder where my jar file is located. I need to do more to the Driver jar file?

Comment: once a remote user access your web, how can he get the JDBC driver from your web host? the file will not be downloaded!

Comment: The Driver can be accessed if I try to access it through the HTTP address.

Comment: it is just because the JDCB jar file is in the classpath of your test machine. try with a clean one and visit it remotely.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking?

Comment: Im not sure what that  will do?

Comment: I resolved the issue by ensure my signing my JDBC driver.Thank You all!